# How to trace or Watch a variable update when executing a python code

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, memory, trace

I am trying to get the number of reads and write into the memory of a variable. to do so I thought of tracing the variable on execution to see the number of updates. therefore, determine the number of read/write to the memory needed. After several searches, I found the package tkinter but I didn't found any way to applying during the execution of a code.

I want to ask if you have any other ideas to determine the number of read/write to the memory that a variable needs. And if I can use tkinter the way described above.

for the [Trace lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html) here is the documentation of it. I've used it on a sample function using the code below:

```py
import trace

tracefunc = t.Trace(count=True, trace=False)

tracefunc.runfunc(hello)

results = tracefunc.results()

results.write_results(coverdir='coverdir2')
```

the results are saved in a directory and a file looks like the screenshot below:
[image]
beside each line there is a number that shows how many times the line is executed.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to trace a normal python variable (very very hard) or do you want to trace a `tkinter` variable (easy)? If you have something like `var = tk.StringVar()` then you can use `var.trace("w", lambda *args: callback())` to trace the variable writes. I think you can replace the `"w"` with `"r"` to trace reads, but I am not sure. `tkinter` is a package for GUIs it is not meant to be used for tracing normal python variables.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I want to trace a normal python variable (I am training a dataset I want to trace the weights during execution). then Tkinter will not work for me. what do you think if I used the trace package that can give me the number of times a line is executed. so for each line I need to define number of read/write to the memory and multiply it by that number using trace package.  this method is hard and needs a lot of time. this is why I wanted feedback if it is a good or a bad idea.

Comment: I have no idea what library you are using so please provide a [mre]. All I can say is that there is no point in using `tkinter` only for tracing variables as it can only trace `tkinter` variables.

Comment: ok. got it thank you.

Comment: Take a look on [watchpoints](https://pypi.org/project/watchpoints/) module.

Comment: ok, that will help. thank you.